# Three JS with website shows no errors but doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, html5-canvas, rendering

I am trying to just copy the example three.js page into my own small website with a canvas where the 3d animation should be added to. But it just shows nothing even though it shows no errors.
I tried figuring it out by myself but nothing seems to work :(

i have my canvas element in one div on the page:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("background");
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.canvas = canvas;
renderer.setSize(canvas.innerWidth, canvas.innerHeight);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00ff00
});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

var animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

```css
#background {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r83/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='background'></canvas>
```

Can you please take a look and show me what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a reason for trying to create your own canvas, you can just let three.js produce its own with the following code:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

With this it creates a new element sets the height and width to match the window and then adds it to the html.

To alter the style further you should use

```
 renderer.domElement.style.attribute = "";
```

and then you just replace attribute with whatever you are trying to modify. 
For more examples you can visit this link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information

Comment: Yes it works, but i want to use my own canvas. I want to use it as the background of my page

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by background of your page? After the new renderer is created it should be possible to modify the css using javascript so I don't see the value in creating a canvas and adding it to the renderer.

Comment: thats also a very good idea. Could you maybe show me how to do that if you have the time? :)

Comment: I added an example and a link for more help if you need it. three.js is designed to create its own canvas so by calling renderer.domElement you can use javascript to interact with the canvas element it creates.

Comment: Yes i just figured it out on my own. i created a empty div on top of the body and used appendChild to get the canvas on top